# logarithmic values of a input file

Tags: r

How do we plot the logarithmic values of an input file which contains floating type numbers. For example, consider my file is in this format:

```
0.000012
0.000234
1.078229
3.246678
```

I want to plot a histogram for logarthmic values of the above values., i.e. for the values given below:

```
log(0.000012)
log(0.000234)
log(1.078229)
log(3.246678)
```

How can i do this using R statistical package?

Comment: That's not a file format -- be careful.  Is your file ASCII, are the values separated with tabs, line feeds, etc?  You may have more trouble reading the data into R than manipulating it subsequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
dat <- c(0.000012, 0.000234, 1.078229, 3.246678)
hist(log(dat))
```